# Condition on Bessel function to be bounded

Tags: bessel-functions, fluid-dynamics

In my lecture notes on Fluid Dynamics there is a derivation on the velocity potential $\Phi$ of waves propagating in a rigid cylinder of radius $R$. The problem is solved by seperation of variables $\Phi(r,\phi,z,t)=Q(r)H(\phi,z,t)$ and after some calculations they arrive at the following equation:
$$\frac{d^2Q}{dr^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{dQ}{dr}+\left(K^2-\frac{m^2}{r^2}\right)Q=0$$

after which they state: "*This is a Bessel equation. There are only bounded solutions that satisfy $v_r=\frac{d\Phi}{dr}=0$ at $r=R$ if $K^2>0$.*"

I don't see why the this statement holds or why it is obvious. Can it be seen easily by looking at the equation or are there some lines of calculations required to proof the result? Any help would by welcome

Thanks in advance.

Comment: These equations are heavily studied an understood. The derivation is long, arduous, disgusting, and probably not worth it. The quick answer is when $K^2>0$ the solutions oscillate and they are called Bessel functions. If $K^2<0$ then the solutions are vaguely exponential and are called Modified Bessel functions, and we know that exponential functions never have a zero derivative.

Comment: Thank you very much, but actually the course notes say "it can be easily shown that...", which suggests there can be given rather easy argument.